# Remove notification on click action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I have a small problem with remove notification on action click.

I read documentation and example code not working, notification don't removed after click.

> Call new notification:

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
    title: "Test",
    message: message,
    playSound: true,
    actions: '["Accept"]',
    tag: `${id}`,
});
```

> Configure and finish notification:

```
PushNotification.configure({
            onNotification: function (notification: any) {
                if (notification.action === 'Accept') {
                    if (orderConnection) {
                        PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: notification.id});
                    }
                }
                notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
            },
            senderID: "YOUR GCM (OR FCM) SENDER ID",
            permissions: {
                alert: true,
                badge: true,
                sound: true
            },
            popInitialNotification: true,
            requestPermissions: true,
        });
```

I tried many times cancel notification but not working at all..
Maybe someone have this same issue?

I using following version of packages:

```
"react": "16.8.2",
"react-native": "0.57.8",
"react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.3",
```